# How to effectively use a map to generate a config based on selected cells in a grid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, dictionary

I have a grid with multiple cells that the user can select.
 Depending on the cells the user selects on the grid, I show different actions at the bottom of the page. The way I’m implementing this right now is as such:

```
const allActionsToShow = {
    action1: false,
    action2: false,
    action3: false,
    action4: false
};

selectedCells.map(cell => {
    if (cell.id === ‘cell1’) { 
        allActionsToShow.action1 = true;
        allActionsToShow.action2 = true;
        hideRemainingActions([‘action3’, ‘action4’]);
    }
    if (cell.id === ‘cell3’) {
        allActionsToShow.action3 = true;
        hideRemainingActions([‘action1’, ‘action2’, ‘action4’])
    }
    if (cell.id === ‘cell4’) {
        allActionsToShow.action4 = true;
        hideRemainingActions([`action1’, `action2`, action3’])
    }
});

const hideRemainingActions = (actionsToHide: string[]) => {
    actionsToHide.map(actionId => {
        allActionsToShow[actionId] = false;
    });
};
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this? If there are 50 actions for example, then I have to manually set those 50 to `true` depending on the cell selected (`if` conditions above) and then pass in the actions I don't want to show to the `hideRemainingActions` function. This would make it difficult to scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do it a bit differently.. since you tagged `reactjs` I wrote up a rough component that you might be able to make use of.

First, you're using `map` to iterate through the `selectedCells` list, but `map` returns an array that you're not using, so it's not exactly the right tool for the job here. Instead I'd just loop through the array using a `forEach`.

I'd define an object that specifies the permissions for each cell, and I'd do it outside the component so it didn't get redefined on every render, or need to be passed to `useEffect` and such.

I'd have a piece of state for the permitted actions, and I'd set them accordingly..

Finally, somewhere in the return, I'd only print the actions that were still permitted.

EDIT: I thought of another way to do it that I like better because it doesn't require iterating through the entire list of cells on every click.. This might be more efficient. I'll keep the original idea at the bottom.

**Here's the new idea**

```
// with this method, we only have to define the actions that aren't allowed by each cell
let permissions = {
    cell1: {
        action3: false,
        action4: false,
    },
    cell3: {
        action1: false,
        action2: false,
        action4: false,
    },
    cell4: {
        action1: false,
        action2: false,
        action3: false,
    }
};

const Whatever = props => {
    
    // all actions are permissable by default, or you can set these to false if you want
    const [permittedActions,setPermittedActions] = useState({
        action1: { permitted: true, because: [] },
        action2: { permitted: true, because: [] },
        action3: { permitted: true, because: [] },
        action4: { permitted: true, because: [] },
    });

    let handleSelect = cell => {
        if ( permissions[cell.id] ) {
            // there are some rules defined for this cell, let's apply them
            setPermittedActions(previousState=>{
                let newState = {...previousState};
                for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(permissions[cell.id])) {
                    if ( !value ) {
                        // whatever action this is, it's not permitted by this cell
                        // we'll keep track of all the cells that don't permit this action
                        newState[key].permitted = false;
                        newState[key].because.push(cell.id);
                    }
                }
                return newState;
            });
        }
    }; // handleSelect

    let handleDeselect = cell => {
        if ( permissions[cell.id] ) {
            // again, rules have been set up for this cell, let's review them
            setPermittedActions(previousState=>{
                let newState = {...previousState};
                for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(permissions[cell.id])) {
                    if ( !value ) {
                        // this cell did not permit the action in question. Let's remove it
                        // from the list
                        newState[key].because = newState[key].because.filter(cellID=>cellID !== cell.id);

                        // are there any cells left that didn't permit this action? If not, we can
                        // set it to be permitted
                        if ( !newState[key].because.length ) {
                            newState[key].permitted = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return newState;
            });
        }
    }; // handleSelect

    return (
        <div>
            {
                // whatever you need for your grid etc etc
                // make sure to add the handlers for when each cell is selected and de-selected
            }
            { permittedActions.action1.permitted && ( <div>action 1 stuff here</div> ) }
            { permittedActions.action2.permitted && ( <div>action 2 stuff here</div> ) }
            { permittedActions.action3.permitted && ( <div>action 3 stuff here</div> ) }
            { permittedActions.action4.permitted && ( <div>action 4 stuff here</div> ) }
        </div>
    );
}; // Whatever
```

**Here's the old idea**

```
let permissions = {
    cell1: {
        action1: true,
        action2: true,
        action3: false,
        action4: false,
    },
    cell3: {
        action1: false,
        action2: false,
        action3: true,
        action4: false,
    },
    cell4: {
        action1: false,
        action2: false,
        action3: false,
        action4: true,
    }
};

const Whatever = props => {
    
    // all actions are permissable by default, or you can set these to false if you want
    const [permittedActions,setPermittedActions] = useState({
        action1: true,
        action2: true,
        action3: true,
        action4: true
    });
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        /* we're going to loop through the list of selected cells and check if
        * a rule has been set for that cell. If so, we'll appy those rules.
        * We'll start out by assuming all actions are permitted, and we'll
        * turn some of them to false as necessary
        */
        let permitted = {
            action1: true,
            action2: true,
            action3: true,
            action4: true
        };
        selectedCells.forEach(cell=>{
            if ( permissions[cell.id] ) {
                // ok there's a list of rules for this cell. let's check them
                for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(permissions[cell.id])) {
                    // is this action still permitted? Is the current rule telling us not to permit it?
                    // if so then we must set this action to false.
                    if ( permitted[key] && !value ) {
                        permitted[key] = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        // ok let's update our state with the new object
        setPermittedActions( permitted );
    },[
        selectedCells
    ]);

    return (
        <div>
            {
                // whatever you need for your grid etc etc
            }
            { permittedActions.action1 && ( <div>action 1 stuff here</div> ) }
            { permittedActions.action2 && ( <div>action 2 stuff here</div> ) }
            { permittedActions.action3 && ( <div>action 3 stuff here</div> ) }
            { permittedActions.action4 && ( <div>action 4 stuff here</div> ) }
        </div>
    );
}; // Whatever
```

Comment: why do you want to do all of that?

Comment: @Hatana I'm not sure what you're asking about in particular. Please be more specific

Answer (score 1):

such function may help if I understood well what you want to do this function receives an array `keysToSetToTrue` where each element is a string indicating the name of the key we want to set it to `true`

```js
const actionsToHide = (keysToSetToTrue) => {
  let updateddActions = { ...allActionsToShow };
  Object.keys(updateddActions).forEach((key) => updateddActions[key] = false);
  keysToSetToTrue.forEach((key) => {
    updateddActions[key] = true;
  });
  let arrayToReturn = [];
  Object.keys(updateddActions).forEach((key) => {
    if (updateddActions[key] === false) arrayToReturn.push(key);
  });
  return arrayToReturn;
};
```

first we copy the object then we set all its keys values to `false` since it will be overridden each time `hideRemainingActions` runs, after that we map through `keysToSetToTrue` array and set each corresponding key value of `updateddActions` to `true`, then,  we just need to return an array where each element is the name of the key we want to hide so we can pass directly the result of this function to `hideRemainingActions`

```js
selectedCells.map(cell => {
 if (cell.id === ‘cell1’) { 
    hideRemainingActions(actionsToHide(["action1","action2"]));
 } 
 //...
})
```

[Try it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgGwQQWFAluCAVEBlACxAHcAueMATxgF4YBvAKBnjUzAEZyAzRCAUwA0zVhnAAmclABOAVyEi4bcAGYefBSyViwAFilyFAXwDcjRqEixt7HCAAS6ACb9aMABQBrfpTt5+ULjYhuTQ0uhgAOYA2gC6AJS0AHwMIggBMLIADk5wUPxOTqg6EG70MAB0VYgoypC4hCQwpiIA8gBGAFb8aBXevu7ZufmFxbbxFdwg0gCiSgTuXj6hMhGRiTQpQ3kFRXUQ0f2xbrwIAvFmLP1+AUGGk9NzwAtLlCvhURspTCws2yN7EqHHzHOgyeSXZoXNIZODSaRwSi4ABKAVk0jA7zWcTccUhHW6vWugxyO1G+wmU1m80W-S+qV+MHQ3A8-12YywwMooJodFO53g8MRKLRGIqWVkEAWdMhRmhLEsEBA6QqCBAkXccIRSJAqKg6LA8pg0lFYEF2pF+oxZhazBsWFwjhc7miACJ7ZxXYIYO66uJXQlLh67E7+C6AOQejjh72Rv0xmBxnS6cOBu37R3OMPRJPsaOxj3iBO51Sp6FAA)

Answer (score -2):

Yes, there's a more efficient and scalable way to achieve this functionality by using a configuration-based approach. Instead of hardcoding the logic for each cell and action, you can create a map that defines the relationships between cells and actions. This approach allows you to easily add more cells and actions without modifying the code that handles the selection logic. Let's see how you can implement this:

1. Define a configuration map that maps each cell ID to the corresponding actions it should enable and disable:

```js
const cellActionConfig = {
  cell1: {
    enableActions: ['action1', 'action2'],
    disableActions: ['action3', 'action4'],
  },
  cell3: {
    enableActions: ['action3'],
    disableActions: ['action1', 'action2', 'action4'],
  },
  cell4: {
    enableActions: ['action4'],
    disableActions: ['action1', 'action2', 'action3'],
  },
  // Add more cells and their corresponding actions here
};
```

2. Create a function to update the `allActionsToShow` object based on the selected cells using the configuration map:

```js
const updateActionsToShow = (selectedCells) => {
  const allActionsToShow = {
    action1: false,
    action2: false,
    action3: false,
    action4: false,
    // Add more actions here
  };

  selectedCells.forEach((cell) => {
    const config = cellActionConfig[cell.id];
    if (config) {
      config.enableActions.forEach((actionId) => {
        allActionsToShow[actionId] = true;
      });
      config.disableActions.forEach((actionId) => {
        allActionsToShow[actionId] = false;
      });
    }
  });

  return allActionsToShow;
};
```

3. Call the `updateActionsToShow` function whenever the user selects cells and update your UI accordingly:

```js
// Assuming you have a function to handle cell selection, e.g., onSelectCell
const selectedCells = [];

const onSelectCell = (cell) => {
  // Add or remove the cell from the selectedCells array based on the user's action
  // For example, you can check if the cell is already selected and then remove it, or vice versa
  // Then call updateActionsToShow(selectedCells) to get the updated actions to show
  const allActionsToShow = updateActionsToShow(selectedCells);
  // Now, update your UI to display the actions based on the updated allActionsToShow object
};
```

By following this approach, you can easily extend the functionality to handle more cells and actions without modifying the core logic of the `updateActionsToShow` function. This makes your code more maintainable and scalable in the long run.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT